# onedit hide rows on another tab (google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been using this script for some time and now need it to hide/unhide rows on a different tab. If the second tab where the row(s) will be hidden/unhidden is called 'Page2" what am I missing in this code to get it to run correctly. Just to clarify the original 'Start Here' tab will still contain the cells that will be used with the 'Yes/No' value

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var arrVals,col,map,rng,rngAddr,row,sh,sheetName,value;
 
  map = {
    'J107':[6,4],
    'J108':[10,4],
    'J109':[14,4],
  }
 
  rng = e.range;
 
  rngAddr = rng.getA1Notation();
  sheetName = rng.getSheet().getName();
  value = e.value;
 
  if (sheetName !== 'Start Here') {
    return;
  }
 
  sh = rng.getSheet();
  arrVals = map[rngAddr];
  row = arrVals[0];
  col = arrVals[1];
 
  if (value == 'Yes') {
    e.range.getSheet().showRows(row,col);
  } else if (value == 'No') {
    e.range.getSheet().hideRows(row,col);
  }
}
```

Comment: e.range.getSheet() is nolonger your desired sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.range.getSheet()` is the sheet that was edited. If you want to access another sheet, you have to use [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) instead.

```
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Page2"); // e.source is the edited spreadsheet, see Reference below
  if (value == 'Yes') {
    sheet.showRows(row,col);
  } else if (value == 'No') {
    sheet.hideRows(row,col);
  }
```

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects > Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple.

Comment: Sorry I thought I did. All set now